# Best way/program/language to call web services asynchronously and save data to mysql database?

Tags: database, web-services, rest, asynchronous

I want to call web services like google books, openlibrary etc., asynchronously and get the book data and store it into my own MySQL server. I want to write a script to do this. It is similar to a web crawler I believe except it does not have to deal with html pages but JSON/XML.

What could be the best way to proceed with this? Can this be done using PHP or NodeJS?

Comment: I don't really understand what part you want to be asynchronous, and why. I think HTTP calls are usually synchronous on the client side. Do you mean you want your application to have concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the api's you are calling are slowing down you application, there is reason to do this asynchronously.

If however you hitting some sort of bottleneck and don't want to keep you application hanging while you get response from these api's than Nodejs will be good choice to do this asynchronously.